# "invisible to" VS "invisible for"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Nomination courses will be visible only **for** the enrolled participants.
> 2. Nomination courses will be visible only **to** the enrolled participants.

When I want to suggest that nomination courses will only be made avalible to enrolled students, which preposition should I choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One group of native speakers might use **to** there, and another might use **for**, and a third group might use these prepositions interchangeably.

*Who is it visible to?* and *Who is it visible for?* could both be paraphrased as "Who can see it?"

Some speakers would recognize this distinction:  **visible to** is a statement of the bald fact that something can be seen and **visible for** is a statement that the visibility is intentional. They were meant to be able to see it.

Some speakers would not recognize that distinction.

Since not all speakers use these prepositions in exactly the same manner, there can be some doubt about whether the visibility is intentional and you will have to rely upon context to make that determination.

Comment: This answer sounds confused and most of all confusing to beginners.

Comment: @Gio: Feel free to write your own unconfused and unconfusing  answer.

Answer (score 7):

"Visible *to*" seems to me the more idiomatic preposition when specifying *who* may see it.

> The total eclipse will only be **visible to** people in northern Europe, although other nearby countries will be able to see the partial eclipse.

You can use "visible *for*" with things like time frame.

> The eclipse will only be **visible for** a short while, from around 8:20 to 8:50 in the morning.

[Edit] I agree with Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer that "visible *to*" indicates who are able to see it while "visible *for*" indicates who are *intended* to see it.  However the distinction is so slight that in order to make the point you should say something like "intended to be visible" or "meant to be visible"

> The study guide **should** only be visible **to** enrolled students.
>
> The study guide **was meant** to be visible only **to** enrolled students, but as we found out yesterday, it's actually visible **to** everyone.

Comment: So visible for in my case sounds strange to native speakers, but it is still understandable?

Comment: @MikePhilip: It doesn’t even sound strange.

Comment: One could even use both, e.g. "The courses will be visible to all enrolled students for the entire registration period." In fact, the modifier "for <time period>" can be applied to almost any expression, even those that idiomatically use "for" for other purposes, too (e.g. "I've been _looking for_ a present _for_ my friend _for_ her graduation _for several months_ already, but I haven't found anything suitable").

Comment: @MikePhilip I doesn't sound particularly strange it spoken English but the word order is convoluted in written English. Why not "Only enrolled participants can view nomination courses"?

Comment: @MikePhilip  I have to disagree with the others, as it sounds strange to me.  But perhaps that's only my personal opinion.  I've edited my answer to signify.

Answer (score 2):

The more commonly used preposition to introduce an object after visible is “***to***”:

[Visible:](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=visible%20)

> PREP. ***to*** - *Its contents were visible to all of them.*

(Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary)